# JS / jQuery : background image onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, background-image, onload

I have function that is supposed to wait till background image is loaded and then add image's ratio to it's container and fade background image container in. It seems to work in Chrome, but fails in Internet explorer 8 and 9, and not always works in 10. In ie8 it doesn't seem to understand jquery on('load') event. In ie 9 and 10 it not always finds width of background image. How can I make it work in ie8+ and other major browsers?

js:

```
$('.item').each(function(index) {
    var thisItem = $(this);
    var image_url = thisItem.find('.img').css('background-image');
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = image_url.replace(/(^url\()|(\)$|[\"\'])/ig, '');
    if (image_url){
    //initialize only when background img is loaded
    var $img = $('<img>').attr('src', img.src).on('load', function(){
        //don't allow img to be larger than it is
        if(img.width < thisItem.width()){thisItem.css({'max-width':img.width+'px'});}
        var ratio = img.height/img.width;
            thisItem.find('.item_ratio').css({'padding-bottom':ratio*100+'%'});
            thisItem.find('.img').fadeIn(800);

        });
    }
});
```

html:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="img" style="background-image:url('some_url'); width: 100%; background-size: cover;"></div>
    <div class="item_ratio"></div>

    <!-- Some other not important html ->

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `load` event on images has been shown to be unreliable/absent, which is why there's [a well-known jQuery plugin](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) to help smoothen things out cross-browser. I'd recommend having a look at that instead rather than trying to figure out the browser issues and edge cases like missing load events when browsers fetch images from cache etc.

Edit: code sample to make it work with a dangling `<img/>` (untested)

```
//initialize only when background img is loaded
var $img = $('<img>').attr('src', img.src).prependTo(thisItem).hide().imagesLoaded(function() {
    //don't allow img to be larger than it is
    //... [your code]
});
```

I used this approach [here](http://dd.ibm.yt/model/66). (The thumbs on the left are a single background image sprite, I animate those in once the image has loaded).

As an aside, you may also be able to use [`background-size: contain`](http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts) in CSS. Doing that might be more performant in newer browsers (if images are large) and much simpler since you don't need any code. It's unsupported in IE8 though, which you can test if you're using Modernizr. That would probably be my preferred approach, but I normally include Modernizr anyway. YMMV.

Comment: Actually that plugin doesn't support background-images which I really need

Comment: I see you're listening for the `load` event on `$('<img>')`. However, you may need to actually insert it into the DOM (hidden) for the `load` to fire. I did this recently and it worked reliably.